# SQL IF/ELSE Statement

Tags: sql, if-statement

I'm struggling to understand why the below SQL will not work. I've put a comment (----------Fine up to Here), which is where SQL Server will accept the code when I parse/save the Store proceedure.

The bit below that, it will not take. Still new to SQL so any help would be great.

The error I receive is, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'. The "ELSE" being the one under the comment I mentioned above.

What I also don't understand is, If I change the IF and the BEGIN round, SQL accepts it (below)? I thought ELSE IF was not possible.

```
----------Fine up to Here
ELSE 
IF (@GrabTypeID = '')
    BEGIN


****************************************
Code below

**************************************
IF  (@GrabtypeID NOT IN (SELECT GRABTYPEID FROM Mytable) AND @GrabtypeID != '')     OR

(@Variable1 NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Mytable) AND @Variable1 !='')                                                                            


BEGIN 
    SELECT @ErrorMessage ='The GrabTypeID or the ID is an invalid value'        
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

PRINT 'Invalid Parameters passed Through'

    RETURN
END 

ELSE 
    BEGIN 

IF (@GrabtypeID ! ='')


TRUNCATE TABLE Datatable1
TRUNCATE TABLE Datatable2

INSERT Datatable1
SELECT * FROM Referencetable1

INSERT Datatable2
SELECT * FROM REFERENCETABLE2

END

----------Fine up to Here

ELSE 
    BEGIN

IF (@GrabTypeID = '')


TRUNCATE TABLE Datatable1
TRUNCATE TABLE Datatable2

INSERT Datatable1 
SELECT * FROM REFERENCETABLE1 WHERE CATEGORY = 4

INSERT Datatable2 
SELECT * FROM REFERENCETABLE2 WHERE CATEGORY = 4

END 

GO
```

Comment: You are missing a BEGIN marker after the IF keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Your format is a little weird.  You could make it work the way you have it, but I think it would be better to use this format:

```
IF expression
BEGIN
SELECT
END
ELSE IF expression
BEGIN
SELECT
END
ELSE IF expression
BEGIN
SELECT
END
```

Specifically, change this:

```
ELSE 
BEGIN 

IF (@GrabtypeID ! ='')
```

To this (in both places):

```
ELSE IF (@GrabtypeID ! ='')
BEGIN
```